# Prevent decimal truncation in Word 2003

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document template which is auto populated via an external web service. The incoming data exists as a currency (e.g. 3.10) but when it is passed into the Word Document template the variable is truncated to remove any trailing 0's. I need the number to always appear with 2 decimals, even if they are both 0's.

This is with the 2003 version of Word, I have not tested with other versions since all of our document templates need to be generated using that version of Word.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to utilize the Format function in a macro to do this:

```
    Format(yourValue, "Currency")
```

To have a user entered text box that can only accept currency formatted values, I've used macros like this:

```
Private Function getValue(text As String) As Currency
    If text = "" Then
        getValue = 0
    Else
        getValue = CCur(Val(RemoveNonNumeric(text)))
    End If
End Function

Private Function RemoveNonNumeric(inputStr As String) As String
    Const NUMERIC_CHARS = "0123456789."

    Dim result As String
    Dim currCharIndex As Long
    Dim currentString As String
    Dim deciCount As Integer
    Dim afterDeciCount As Integer

    deciCount = 0
    afterDeciCount = 0

    For currCharIndex = 1 To Len(inputStr)
        currentString = Mid$(inputStr, currCharIndex, 1)

        If currentString = "." Then deciCount = deciCount + 1

        If InStr(1, NUMERIC_CHARS, currentString) > 0 And deciCount < 2 And afterDeciCount < 3 Then
            result = result + currentString
            If deciCount > 0 Then afterDeciCount = afterDeciCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    result = result

    RemoveNonNumeric = result
End Function
```